# Changing tracelevel filter setting in EventFlow without calling constructor again?

Tags: event-flow

Is there way change a filter on the fly? I'm considering using EventFlow with Service Fabric, but would like to have the ability to for example change the tracelevel without having to restart the service and feeding it a new json config file with a different tracelevel setting. Is this possible?

Thanks,
Hans

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the current EventFlow implementation does not have this capability.

Comment: Thanks, Karol. I also just came across this comment in the code, further confirming your answer: "// TODO: dynamically re-configure the pipeline when configuration changes, without stopping the service"